# git get error: "Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized"

Tags: ssl, gitlab

When I run something like:
 `git clone https://gitlab.mydoman.com/test.git` 
from part of the clients, I get the error:

> Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized

I saw 2 main solution:
 
1. User can set 
   export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true
2. to install root certificates

I would like to solve the problem to all the users.
I did not understood how to install the root certificate and where I configure Gitlab to use it. Is there url to clear instruction?

Thanks.

Comment: Since the root certificate is used to create a trust path to the servers (gitlab) certificate it must be installed as trusted on each clients machine.  Installing it centrally on the server will not help.